# How can I use CNAME in Bind properly?

Tags: dns, bind

I'm new to Bind/DNS and want to point/map SMTP, webmail and IMAP to my domain but a check in nslookup is failing. How can I nslookup SMTP this way?

The error I get is: `smtp.stylez24.com: NXDOMAIN`

In my forward zone file I have this, wich lets me nslookup my domain but not SMTP:

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     server.stylez24.com.     admin.stylez24.com. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
  ;


   stylez24.com.            IN      NS              stylez24.com.
   stylez24.com.            IN      A               192.168.10.1

   @                       IN      A               127.0.0.1
   @                       IN      AAAA            ::1
   www                     IN      CNAME           stylez24.com.
   smtp                    IN      CNAME           stylez24.com.
   stylez                  IN      A               192.168.10.1
   smtp.stylez24.com       IN      A               192.168.10.2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.stylez24.com.     admin.stylez24.com. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
  ;


   @                       IN      NS              stylez24.com.
   @                       IN      A               192.168.10.1
   @                       IN      A               127.0.0.1
   @                       IN      AAAA            ::1

                           IN      A               192.168.10.1
   ns                      IN      A               192.168.10.1
   stylez24.com.           IN      A               192.168.10.1

   www                     IN      CNAME           ns

   stylez                  IN      A               192.168.10.1

   smtp                    IN      A               192.168.10.1
                           IN      MX              10   smtp

   smtp2                   IN      A               192.168.10.2
                           IN      MX              20   smtp2
```

Comment: -The error of NXDOMAIN caused because by the definition of domain before the definition of the IP address of domain name.
like this:

   stylez24.com.            IN      NS              stylez24.com.
   stylez24.com.            IN      A               192.168.10.1

Comment: Didnt work, still get NXDOMAIN with this setting too. Here is my dig smtp 
                                                                    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> smtp
          ;; global options: +cmd
          ;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27358
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;smtp.    IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.   533 IN SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2014051700 1800 900 604800 86400

Comment: -Well take look now, think about it this solved your problem! I performed the test here with this address and domain worked perfectly, take a look around and see if this is entirely correct as it should, anything just tell me.

Comment: Still not working ,smtp. nxdomain. Could the problem me come from another file ? Thanks for your efforts btw ;)

Comment: Update: I got it to work finally,using one IP:              Stylez24 IN A 192.168.10.1
smtp IN CNAME  stylez24.com.